# python-igraph multiprocessing task

Tags: python, multiprocessing, igraph

I'm using python-igraph for my task. Let's say, we have a big weighted directed graph and for each node we want to mark out it's edges with a special flag (add an attribute to it) if it's weight is significant (for example top-n by weight). Obviously, this operation can be done in parallel way, because it is independent for each node. So I've decided to use multiprocessing. But it seems I'm doing something wrong, because graph doesn't change. One process version works.

Here is a [sample graph](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4JKldGNJPOTMjU2UTAtZ1JiWEk/edit?usp=sharing).  Here is a way I'm doing it:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from igraph import Graph
from enum import Enum
import multiprocessing as mp

MAXIMUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSES = 4

class EdgeType(Enum):
    Distance = 0
    ListOfNeighbors = 1


class ClustGraph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__graph = None

    def create_short_graph(self):
        graph = self.__graph
        print graph.es[0]

        queue = mp.JoinableQueue()
        [queue.put(vertex.index) for vertex in graph.vs]
        [queue.put(None) for i in range(MAXIMUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSES)]
        workers = []
        for i in range(MAXIMUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSES):
            worker = mp.Process(target=ClustGraph.__create_neighbors_list_parallel, args=(self, queue))
            workers.append(worker)
            worker.start()
        queue.join()

        print graph.es[0]

    def load(self, f):
        self.__graph = Graph.Read_Ncol(f)
        self.__graph.es['type'] = [{EdgeType.Distance} for i in xrange(len(self.__graph.es))]

    @staticmethod
    def __create_neighbors_list(vertex, graph, p, n):
        edges = graph.es.select(_from=vertex)
        size = int(max(len(edges) * p, n))
        short_edges = dict(sorted([(edge, edge['weight']) for edge in edges], key=lambda (k, v): v, reverse=True)[:size]).keys()
        [e['type'].add(EdgeType.ListOfNeighbors) for e in short_edges]

    def __create_neighbors_list_parallel(self, queue, p=0.05, n=7):
        while True:
            vertex = queue.get()
            if vertex is None:
                break
            ClustGraph.__create_neighbors_list(vertex, self.__graph, p, n)
            queue.task_done()
        queue.task_done()


def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--input')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    graph = ClustGraph()
    graph.load(args.input)
    graph.create_short_graph()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, if there are any best-practice for such task, I'll be glad to know about them.

P.S. enum is [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)

Comment: I've realized, that problem is synchronization actually. So, the question is - is there any possibility to work with python-igraph in multiprocessing way?

Comment: I suspect that there are as many copies of your initial graph in memory as the number of workers you have started (i.e. each worker gets its own copy of the graph, and then it works on the copy). You could probably use a `multiprocessing.Pipe` object to send the neighbor lists back to the main process that spawned the workers, and then you can simply update the graph in the main process.